# jQuery click checkbox doesn't check in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

Specifically, an in memory dom of input type checkbox does not receive the 'checked' attribute (or any other checked indicator) in FireFox.

The commented line can be uncommented to see the test pass, but currently you will see the test fail in firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/mE3xb/2/

```
var cb = $('<input type="checkbox" />')
//var cb = $('input'); 
if (cb.is(':checked')) alert("checkbox says it's already checked"); 
cb.click(); 
if (cb.is(':checked')) alert("checkbox clicked correctly!"); 
else alert("fail!");
```

Am I doing non-standard things?  Any advice?  I'm essentially relying on the jQuery .click to actually check my checkbox in the UI (and I don't want to use .attr, .prop, .val because it will break my nice encapsulation that I got going on.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery 1.4.3, it looks like your best bet will be:

```
cb[0].setAttribute('checked', 'checked'); // plain old vanilla JS
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mE3xb/11/)** - tested in FireFox & Chrome & IE8

`.click()` doesn't work in many strange situations in Firefox (it is something inherently wrong/different in that browser). I would assume because it isn't actually available on the DOM yet, so it doesn't know where this event would be. This is one of the many reasons things like `.prop()` exist, etc.

Comment: Updated my answer for jQuery 1.4.3

Comment: So is the answer to the question: 'Firefox implements checkboxes in such a way that jQuery's in memory DOM cannot simulate things like .click() on it?'  Why is it that it works in all other browsers?  Even the latest version of jQuery DOES NOT WORK in FF.

Comment: And for the last time, I am aware you can use things like setAttribute, attr etc...  I am asking about the click() in IN MEMORY DOM not working in FireFox.

Comment: And to be fair to me, since my specific question is sweeping across all version of jQuery it should not matter what version of jQuery I have!

Comment: Well you are extremely rude... And if it wasn't obvious enough... `.click()` doesn't work in many strange situations in Firefox (it is something inherently wrong/different in that browser). I would assume because it isn't actually available on the DOM yet, so it doesn't know where this event would be. This is one of the many reasons things like `.prop` exist, etc. Good luck

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for!  Put this in the main answer and I will mark it as correct answer to my question.  :)  Sorry if I sounded rude...

Answer (score 4):

Use `cb.prop('checked', true)` instead of `cb.click()` to check your checkboxes

**Fiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/mE3xb/7/**

Comment: I'm on jquery 1.4.3 and attr does work.  However, this is not the solution I'm looking for.  FF is the only browser my click method doesn't work for, and so if there is any way to make it work for in memory dom then that would be awesome!)  If not, the correct answer is "no" and not what you have suggested.

Comment: @mrjustinmooser side note: post that you are using a very old version of jQuery next time.

Comment: True, I am sorry mcpDESIGNS!  @Nico I'll give trigger a shot!

Comment: Trigger does not work either in FireFox.  I believe there will be no way to accomplish what I'm trying to do in FireFox, but I have not cited the specific reason why jQuery's in memory dom is broken in the scenario presented on FireFox.  This is likely a FireFox implementation detail that jQuery cannot get around, however.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just stumbled on an answer that worked for me for my unit test:

First, I toggle the checked property:

```
checkbox4[0].checked = !checkbox4[0].checked;
```

Then after that, I trigger "just" the click handler (by using triggerHandler it doesn't actually check/uncheck the box again on other browsers)

```
checkbox4.triggerHandler( "click" );
```

This simulates an user "clicking" the checkbox, and checking/unchecking it. Not as encapsulated as you might like it to be for your needs (from reading the above comments and answers) but it seems to get a slightly more thorough job done of it than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. triggerHandler did it for me. Can you explain why .click does not work?