# Checkbox works in chrome not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes, the first of which must be selected if none of the subsequent boxes are not checked and this first box must be deselected if any of the following boxes are checked.

I also want to make sure that the user can select the checkboxes by clicking on the image to the right of the box (both are in the same 'li').

I also want all of the checkboxes below the first one to deselect if a user selects the first checkbox.

I have all of that working fine in Textmate and in Chrome. The only thing that is not working in Firefox(v. 26) is the part when the user clicks directly on the checkbox of the first 'li'. They can click on the span to the right of it, the checkbox will be selected and the subsequent boxes will deselect, but I really want that click to work in the box as well!

Here is my code in action! http://jsfiddle.net/Pdn87/2/

Thank you for your help with this!

CSS:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
    position:relative;
}

.stars {
    border:0px solid red;
    width:70%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin: 10px 0 0 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size:14px;
}

.rating {
    width:70%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin: 10px 0 -5px 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size:14px;
}

.highlight {
    background-color:rgb(63, 130, 255);
    border: 0px solid rgb(63, 130, 255);
    border-radius:10px;
    top:-10px;
}

.starRating {
    color:transparent;
}

.star-ratings ul, .star-ratings li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -30px;
}

.sub {
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    width:40%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sub sub2">
<ul class="star-ratings">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="S0" checked> <span class="stars">All (includes unrated)
                                <br><br>
                            <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox S1"> <img class="stars" src="http://leangreenmovingmachine.com/upload/5-Star.png">
                            <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox S2"> <img class="stars" src="http://leangreenmovingmachine.com/upload/4-Star.png">
                            <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox S3"> <img class="stars" src="http://leangreenmovingmachine.com/upload/3-Star.png">
                            <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox S4"> <img class="stars" src="http://leangreenmovingmachine.com/upload/2-Star.png">
                            <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox S5"> <img class="stars" src="http://leangreenmovingmachine.com/upload/1-Star.png">
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                                <br><br>

<div class="sub sub3" >
<ul class="star-ratings">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="R0" checked> <span class="stars">All (includes unrated)
                                <br><br>
                            <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox R1"> <img class="rating" src="http://leangreenmovingmachine.com/upload/Star%20Rating%20FIVE.png">
                            <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox R2"> <img class="rating" src="http://leangreenmovingmachine.com/upload/Star%20Rating%20FOUR.png">
                            <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox R3"> <img class="rating" src="http://leangreenmovingmachine.com/upload/Star%20Rating%20THREE.png">
                            <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox R4"> <img class="rating" src="http://leangreenmovingmachine.com/upload/Star%20Rating%20TWO.png">
                            <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox R5"> <img class="rating" src="http://leangreenmovingmachine.com/upload/Star%20Rating%20ONE.png">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".star-ratings").on("mouseover", ".stars, .rating", function () {
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});

$(".star-ratings").on("mouseout", ".stars, .rating", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
});

$('.star-ratings').on('click', '.stars, .rating', function () {
    if ($(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
        if (!$(this).closest('.star-ratings').find('li').find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('.star-ratings').find(':checkbox:first').prop('checked', true);
        }
    } 
    else {
        $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).closest('.star-ratings').find(':checkbox:first').prop('checked', false);
    }

});


$('.star-ratings').change(':checkbox', function () {
    if ($(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('.star-ratings').find('li:first').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    } 
    else {
        $(this).closest('.star-ratings').find(':checkbox:first').prop('checked', true);
    }
});

$('.star-ratings').on("click", ".stars:first", function () {
    if (!$(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).closest('li').siblings().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$(".star-ratings").on('click', ':checkbox:first', function () {
    if (!$(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).closest('li').siblings().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$('.star-ratings').on("click", "#R0", function () {
    if (!$(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).closest('li').siblings().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: hugely inefficient and no need to use both change and click

Comment: i think `click` does not work on checkboxes in firefox http://stackoverflow.com/q/14463971 (not quite the same problem, but i think its the same reason)

Comment: I have tried both click and change. neither seem to work for the way I have my jQuery set up. I left both on there to show that neither are working. What specific changes do you think would help with my efficiency?

Comment: OKAY! that really helped - i changed anything that was linked with a checkbox to "change" instead of "click". Then I had to add another if statment to one of the functions and delete another one that came later and still, after those were changed there was one other fix that I needed. here is the new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pdn87/6/

Thank you two for your help!

Comment: I'd like to share a link for handling change (not just click) for select box, chechbox and radio buttons. Also look at the comments - there are examples for each case you would need: http://jivebay.com/handling-checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-select-options-in-jquery/ (it helped me for more than 15 projects so far...)!