# Firefox: Click and change events on checkbox elements which are not appended into document tree

Tags: javascript, firefox, checked

I created a fragment of HTML-code with a radio-group. But I didn't append this fragment into document tree because I need to configure this fragment using the click event of the first radio-element BEFORE I will show it to users.

I use JQuery to set click handler. After that I call this handler through input.click(). The handler works but the property *CHECKED* in radio-element doesn't change until radio-element is not appended into document tree. Only FF behaves so - other browsers (IE, Chrome, Safari) change this property. When I appended the radio-element into the document tree then FF could change this property. Can you explain to me why FF behaves so, please?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#do').click(function() {
    var input1 = $('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"></input>');
    input1.click(function() {
      console.log('click => ' + (this.checked ? 'true' : 'false'));
    });
    input1.change(function() {
      console.log('change => ' + (this.checked ? 'true' : 'false'));
    });
    input1.click(); // output: click => false
    $('#result').append(input1); /*Will append not checked element*/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="do">Click me</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

PS Checkbox-elements behave also

Comment: I encountered this issue while running unit tests with Karma. None of our DOM elements are in the document tree, so testing checkbox functionality would fail in Firefox, but pass in Chrome and PhantomJS. Inspired by the `setAttribute()` solution below, we used jQuery's `attr()` to simulate a check.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bug in FF,.click() doesn't work well in FF.

You can achieve the checked functionaliy in all browsers via:

```
input1[0].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wj6pMXfhkPE8S3URevDb?p=preview)

find a similar question in SO.

[jQuery click checkbox doesn't check in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463971/jquery-click-checkbox-doesnt-check-in-firefox)

Comment: I must use click handler because it declares relations between statuses of components and between data. 
I has thought already to do own click-method for this situation. But I hope still that it isn't necessary

Comment: Not understand "it declares relations between statuses of components and between data", but you can wrap "input1[0].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');" into the custom input.click function to achieve your purpose

Comment: huan feng, what will happen in time of next click-events? The instruction 'input.setAttribute("checked","checked")' won't deactivate this element. It will be 'checked' forever. It need to set own property (for example '_chd') and to change this property every click-event through checkbox.checked = checkbox._checked = !checkbox._chd
Relations between DOM-elements: for example, if checkbox is checked then some DOM-container is visible, but if checkbox isn't checked then container is hidden. That is simple example. In reality relations are more complex. Only handler can regulate such relations.

Comment: you can bind the custom click event, and set the attribute to the opposite value, like checked = !currentChecked

Comment: I said the same: to do the property '_checked' which will be changed by every click. Original 'checked' will be equivalent '_checked'